# Modifying PDF file with Matlab by fopen

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to use matlab to fopen a PDF file, manually replace a string ('Helvetica') with a new string ('Arial')? Probably due to the fact that the file is part binary and part ascii, if I

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
str = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid);

newStr = strrep(str, 'Helvetica', 'Arial');

fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s', newStr);
fclose(fid);
```

The PDF will be unusable at all. Is there a way to avoid this?

PS: 1) The PDF file may have very different sizes, so skipping a certain amount of binary data may be difficult;
    2) I know how to do it in python, but I'd really like to see whether it could be done by pure MATLAB...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to read the pdf as uint8 instead of char and write out with fwrite

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
bytes = fread(fid, 'uint8')';
fclose(fid);

% Do the replacement 

% NB: strrep complains about the byte array but works anyway
%     You could do replacement without using string function
%     but this works.  

output = strrep(bytes,'Helvetica','Arial');    

% Write out the modified pdf    

fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
fwrite(fid, output);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I edited the original post from 'r' and 'w' to 'rb' and 'wb' to get it working though. Thanks again!

Comment: @ShawnWang.  I'm surprised you need to use rb & wb.  The Matlab documentation for fopen says that the default mode for fopen is binary and that files are only opened in text mode if rt/wt are used.  Anyway, good to hear it worked for you.

Comment: Hmm...I tried the r w/o b first, but it in fact corrupted the PDF file. And only by adding the 'b' did it start to work... Weird... Probably there is a version difference? I am using 7.14 64-bit windows. Anyways, I am so glad that it worked!